# PHP and htaccess weird issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, function, mod-rewrite, routes

I'm working on a project, and I want my link to be like /cars/add (Routing) for example,
and I wrote a function that got the link and processed it to be as above and wrote it to htaccess. So far everything goes well, but the weird thing is the htaccess is not working unless I add a space or new line.

Here is my test:

```
function getLink() {
  $link =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $base = dirname($link);

  $flink = str_replace($base,'',$link);
  $flink = str_replace('/','',$flink);
  $tor = $flink;
  $flink = str_replace('.php?action=','/',$flink);

  if (strpos($link,'.php')) {

    whtaccess($tor,$flink);
  }
}

function whtaccess($link,$rlink) {
  $filename = ".htaccess";
  $f = fopen($filename,'a+');
  $string = sprintf("\rRewriteRule %s %s",$rlink,$link);

  $htacess = file_get_contents($filename);
  if (strpos($htacess,$string)==true) {
    fclose($f);
    header("Location:".$rlink);
  } else {
    fwrite($f,$string);
    fclose($f);

    header("Location:".$rlink);
  }
}
```

Do you know what can help me?

Comment: What error do you get? You should consider updating your post for clarity.

Comment: are you trying to do "pretty urls" where everything is handled by a controller (or several controllers)?  if so, i would recommend another solution to you.  the security risks of what you are attempting must be *very* high since the request from the uri is going to end up writing into your htaccess, which should never be writable or readable for the Internet.

Comment: Education. That is some seriously awful code. Fix the URLs in the published content, not in the browser's address bar. Then, as @WEBjuju said, learn about routing.